# Inserting a character in a file name using Python

Tags: python-2.7, filenames

I am new to Python.

So, I have a couple of files like:

- r_feature_info_call_home_cbr_16_6.xml
- r_feature_info_flap_list_ts_cbr_16_6.xml

I want to remove all the '_' from the file name except the ones after the first 'r' and the one before '16_6'

I am trying to write some code:

```
import os

fpath = os.path.join('/Users/avishdas/Documents/Duplication Script/', 'Feature_Info')

flist = os.listdir(fpath)

for f in flist:
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    file_name = (file_name.replace("_", ""))
    ufile_name = os.rename(file_name, file_name.([ :1] + '_' + [1: ]))
    print ufile_name
```

With this piece of code, I am first removing all the underscores and then trying to insert the two '_'.

The code works fine till:

```
file_name = (file_name.replace("_", ""))
```

The next line is giving me an invalid syntax error. Please note that here I am just trying to add the '_' after the first 'r'.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Comment: what's `[ :1]` ? you want to save the result of `replace` in a new variable, say: `new_file_name` and then: `os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)`. By the way, the outer parenthesis here are redundant: `file_name = (file_name.replace("_", ""))`

Comment: Does't [ :1] imply start from the index 0 till 1? Yes, the brackets are redundant. Also, if I do the os.rename like you said, I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: "start" of what ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the issues I can see:

- you overwrite your `file_name` variable (line 9) and assume it still contains the original file name on the next line (line 10). Use one more intermediary variable
- you forgot to add your extension `file_ext` back when you call `os.rename`. You need it on the first argument - it is up to you if you want it on the second argument.
- you expect `os.rename` to return something interesting, it is going to return `None` on success and throw an `Exception` on failure (which you may want to handle)
- you can't use parentheses after a `.`, that's your invalid syntax.
- finally, your idea with substrings to reintroduce the _ is correct but it may be hard at the end of your file if the number of characters after the last _ varies because you won't be able to know the exact position.

Additional note: if you intend to keep the `.xml` extension, you may not need to split your filename.

Here is an example without assuming the length of each segment:

```
for f in flist:
    elements = f.split("_") # make a list of elements without _
    elements.insert(1, "_") # reintroduce the first _ in the list
    elements.insert(-1, "_") # reintroduce the last _ in the list
    new_name = "".join(elements) # recreate a string
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted. I do get an 'No such file or directory' error, but I have managed to fix it by using the absolute path in os.rename.